# Analytical solution of 2D Laplace equation with discontinuous BCs.

Tags: heat-equation

I was trying to obtain analytical solution of 2D Laplace equation. I understood the [standard procedure](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3398177/876381) which involved the Method of separation of variable.

I was trying to obtain the exact solution of Laplace equation with these BCs.

u(0,y)=0, u(1,y)=0, u(x,0)=1, u(x,1)=1. The domain is a unit square and FEM solution looks similar to this one (x limit is different in the figure).

[image]

The solution contains discontinuity at the corners. This indicates that the exact solution should be a piecewise function. How do I even approach this problem to obtain an exact piecewise solution?

I found several [publications](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021999118302444) where people have used exact solution for 2D diffusion equation with discontinuous coefficients.

Comment: You can't conclude a piecewise solution from discontinuous boundary conditions. Your numeric solutions looks smooth except at the corners but I don't know whether a nice analytic solution can be written down.